# How do I display unsupported emoji on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, emoji

OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 by default can't display some emoji, for example the ["Cloud with rain" emoji](http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/904/new/cloud-with-rain): .

How can I view such problematic emoji? Do I need to install a custom font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied these two files from El Capitan and replaced the default ones (I recommend making backups):

```
/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Color Emoji.ttf
/System/Library/Input Methods/CharacterPalette.app/Contents/Resources/Category-Emoji.plist
```

After a reboot I have all emojis in Yosemite.

Comment: Be carefull, the solution from @shrx breaks your system if you copy the files from OSX Sierra !

Comment: @Ouatataz - why and how it breaks the system?

Answer (score -2):

From the iOS 9.1 [emoji list](http://emojipedia.org/apple/)...
[image: clip]

These are also in the emoji font of Mac OS 10.11 (El Capitan).
Are they really not in Yosemite?  Then the solution is upgrade to El Capitan.

Comment: My question is how to display them on Yosemite.